# No properties tab in layout resource editor

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently uninstalled and reinstalled eclipse with android sdk. Now I don't see the properties tab in the layout resource editor.

Suggestions?

Update: This is all I see in "window > open perspective > other"
[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Properties

Comment: I kept trying ...other->Android->View Properties, but that didn't work!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Window -> Open Perspective -> Other (if not on list) -> Properties (or similar)